Excel VBA Set External Data Range Properties in VBA Code
My Data source is a connection from SQL. I recorded a macro to set AdjustColumnWidth to False.  When I run the macro, It bombs on .RowNumbers = False with Error "Object variable or With block variable not set" (Run-time error '91')
What am I doing wrong?
Range("CCA_XXXXXXXXX[[#All],[NPI]]").Select
        With Selection.ListObject.QueryTable
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        End With



Why are you using Select?

Also, I cannot reproduce your problem with the code you show.

Just open any Excel Workbook, Connect to an external Data Source and import as table (I used a table in SQL), Record Macro:  Select Column, Goto Data Menu, Properties, and Uncheck Adjust Column Width.  Stop Recording Macro.  Then try running the macro.  I could send an example file...  I'd just have to make sure there isn't any HIPPA Information in it.

FYI, I just did a test database and imported the data from the same Excel worksheet (Just 2 columns), and the macro worked.  So it must have something to do with the SQL Query connection?

That is what I did. And it worked.

Did you try with an SQL Connection?  That is where I am having problems.  thank you for your time.

Yes, I did. Your problem is likely in code or other information you have not shared.
